# How to add Upload Assemblies Add-in to Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: templating

Does anybody know how to add this Addin to Visual Studio 2013? I have read that Addins are deprecated in VS2013...

Is something special needed to make this work?

Answer (score 6):

OK, to answer my own question:

Follow these steps to add the UploadAssemblies2.dll to VS2013:

- Find your Projects location (in VS2013 TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Projects location);
- Create an "Addins" directory and copy&paste the content of the Upload Assemblies zip
  file to this directory;
- Update the Upload Assemblies2.AddIn file:

  - Change version to 12.0 (both occurrences);
  - Change DLL location to \Addins\UploadAssemblies2.dll
- Start VS2013, navigate to TOOLS -> Add-in Manager, and check all three checkboxes
  (Startup, Command Line and in front of the Add-in);
- Close and re-open VS2013. Now you see the 2 options for Uploading
  assemblies under TOOLS.

Comment: I had  an issue to let this work in VS2012.  But this answer pointed me in the good direction.
The difference for VS2012 was that the version in the Upload Assemblies2.AddIn file had to be set to 11.0 instead of 12.0.  After that the 2 options were  visible in the TOOLS menu.  So no need to check the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

Edwin's solutions worked for me, except that:

I had to manually 'unblock' the .dll file by right-clicking on the dll, selecting properties and clicking 'unblock'. Until I unblocked the dll I got an unknown error. This is actually described in the official documentation:

**[Upload Assembly 2.0 Add-In for Visual Studio](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/AssemblyUploader2.aspx)**

Also for some reason the projects location didn't work for me. Instead I put the files in a custom location and added that path in **Tools -> options -> Environment -> Add-in security**